# Google Tango - Fetch exposure time from TangoImageBuffer?

Tags: c++, casting, android-ndk, google-project-tango

I'm trying to read the exposure time from the `TangoImageBuffer` struct and I always see garbage values in it. It starts with 0 and randomly changes to a huge positive number and also negative numbers sometimes.

I basically cast the `exposure_time_ns` value to `%lld` when I'm printing it out. Also when I try to convert the huge numbers to seconds, it doesn't make sense since it ends up being more than 100 seconds.

The `exposure_time_ns` is an int64_t datatype. Am I casting it wrong or is there a different way to fetch it?

**MVCE** - I'm using a *point to point* sample from the tango c examples available in github. Here's the link to it-
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_point_to_point_example

I just changed the way in which the *OnFrameAvailable* callback is handled and I have attached it below.

```
void PointToPointApplication::OnFrameAvailable(const TangoImageBuffer* buffer) {
      TangoSupport_updateImageBuffer(image_buffer_manager_, buffer);
      int64_t exposure = 0;
          double timestamp = 0;
          TangoImageBuffer* currentBuffer = nullptr;
          {
              std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_tangobufferLock);

              TangoSupport_getLatestImageBuffer(image_buffer_manager_,
                                                       &currentBuffer);
              if(currentBuffer == nullptr)
              {
                  LOGE("Color Buffer manager retrieval issue\n");
                  return;
              }
              else
              {
                  exposure = currentBuffer->exposure_duration_ns;
                  timestamp = currentBuffer->timestamp;
              }
          }
        }
```

I print the exposure values, every frame and among all the TangoImageBuffer attributes, only the exposure and the frame number are holding garbage values and all other values are valid.

Comment: Could post a MVCE snippet?

Comment: @efekctive - Hello, I'm basically using one of the Tango C examples, the point to point example - [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_point_to_point_example). The small change that I'm making to it is in the ImageOnFrameAvailable callback function. I'm attaching the code block for it below.